# How to set name in route group in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5

I'm using [this](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) package in my project and there have default package [routes](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/master/routes/voyager.php).

**Like this:**

[image]

I want use this route in my controller. I'm trying to use with name but it did not work this way.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});

And 

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
})->name('admin');
```

**I'm trying to use like this:**
       [image]

I want to give access like this, as if I'm trying to access 'admin' route then I could access all routes under these route group. I don't know how I will do that?

Please help me.

Comment: What does "but didn't work" even mean? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what dose `php artisan route:list` tell you

Comment: Thanks for you replay, Showing all routes list with 'as' => 'admin' these way. In my question first way. Like this (http://prntscr.com/guhhm7)

Comment: Why are you providing screenshots instead of actual text from copy/paste? And what are we supposed to do with a hard-to-read low-contrast semi-transparent route:list screenshot?

Comment: There is many route in list that's why i'm giving image and sorry for this fault. I'm create a gist for route (https://gist.github.com/themeyellow/50e9cc48563385e2129c3029c3a53860) and thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to route with name `admin.` because such route doesn't exist.

When you use:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

it means all routes created by `Voager::routes()` will have name starting with `admin.` but it doesn't mean `admin.` route exist.

So I assume you should instead use rather `admin.voyager.dashboard` instead, so you should rather use:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.voyager.dashboard');
```

instead of:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.');
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thanks so much for your ans. I'm follow your step 'elseif ($this->setCompany == 'admin') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.voyager.dashboard');
        }' and there showing this error (InvalidArgumentException
Route [admin.voyager.dashboard] not defined.)

Comment: Looking at the screen you provided https://prnt.sc/guhhm7 or this file https://gist.github.com/themeyellow/50e9cc48563385e2129c3029c3a53860 it's defined. Make sure you didn't removed it after you paste this. And make sure to run `php artisan route:list`. Also I don't know what exactly is in your middleware - you might be getting 404 also because of your middlewares

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Here is update route list 'https://gist.github.com/themeyellow/50e9cc48563385e2129c3029c3a53860'. If is there any middlewares issues how i will find out? Please tell me clearly.